# I am trying to setup the vagrant environment but this error occurs default: VM not created. Moving on

Tags: vagrant, virtual-machine, virtualbox, box

I am working on to setup the vagrant environment on the mac. I have done the following steps.

- Installed the virtualbox
- Clone my project to local disk
- Downloaded the box and added the box successfully
- I have also edit the vagrant file and add the name of box to the vagrant file.

Now when i run the command "vagrant provision" this error occurs

```
default: VM not created. Moving on...
```

I have google it a lot but no idea that what to do.

```
sudo vagrant box list
Result:
bpc_box (virtualbox, 0)
new_box (virtualbox, 0)
```

Vagrant file
    VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION = "2"

```
Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|
  config.vm.box = "bpc_box"

  config.vm.synced_folder "workspace/", "/vagrant"

  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 8080, host: 8085
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 80,   host: 8090

  config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
    vb.cpus   = 2
    vb.memory = 2048
  end

  config.vm.provider "parallels" do |prl|
    prl.cpus   = 2
    prl.memory = 2048
  end

  config.ssh.forward_agent = true

  config.vm.provision "ansible" do |ansible|
    ansible.playbook = "provisioning/main.yml"
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to spin the VM first, the first command to run is

```
$ vagrant up
```

this will bring your VM up and provision it if this is the first time this particular VM has been started.

once the VM is up and running you can run `vagrant provision` to force the (re)provisioning of the running VM.

You can read more about vagrant cli option at https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/cli/

Comment: VagrantFile contained the name of box from the live server and when I run the "vagrant up" it begins downloading the box from the server but I have already downloaded the box so I added my own box name to the vagrant file and then run the "vagrant provision". What should i do??

Comment: no - its probably something wrong and a gap between the name of the box you have in Vagrantfile and the box name you have added - add your Vagrantfile in your question and the result of the command `vagrant box list`

Comment: Edit the file with your requirements

Comment: you should not need sudo to run your commands .. `vagrant up` should not download the box unless you have another default provider, run `vagrant up --provider virtualbox` and show the output

Comment: Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> default: Importing base box 'bpc_box'...

Comment: There was an error while executing `VBoxManage`, a CLI used by Vagrant
for controlling VirtualBox. The command and stderr is shown below.

Command: ["startvm", "fd69c689-4d2f-4d01-8a19-ec50ccff2ef9", "--type", "headless"]

Stderr: VBoxManage: error: VT-x is not available (VERR_VMX_NO_VMX)
VBoxManage: error: Details: code NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005), component ConsoleWrap, interface IConsole

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142629/discussion-between-john-and-frederic-henri).

Comment: thats different issue .. basically you need to enable VT-x in BIOS, check this error in google, there are tons of info for this